# Response in 202 STATUS in Retrofit2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

i  want to convert the Response  in to JSON and show it to the User .I was able to display 200 response but in 202,i am failed.

```
{



            Log.d(TAG, "RESPONSE CODE" + response.code());
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                SuccessResponse signupResponse = response.body();
                String sSignupResponse = gson.toJson(signUpResponse, SuccessResponse.class);
                try {

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else if (response.code() == 202) {
                Log.d(TAG,"RESPONSE CODE IS "+"202 RIGHT");
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                SuccessResponse signupResponse = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG,"WHAT IS sSignupResponse"+signupResponse.toString());
                String sSignupResponse = gson.toJson(signUpResponse.toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"WHAT IS sSignupResponse"+sSignupResponse.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(sSignupResponse);
                    Log.d(TAG,"WHAT IS jsonObject"+jsonObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                //request not successful (like 400,401,403 etc)
                //Handle errors
                Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> converter = ApiClient.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
                try {
                    ErrorResponse errors = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                    dialogUtil.showOkDialog(errors.getMessage().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    dialogUtil.showOkDialog(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }

        }
```

should i do the same for 202 too?
i created another POJO like ErrorResponse with message and code ,replaced the SuccessRespone with ErrorResponse

Comment: post whole your code will help better

Comment: @PhanDinhThai can you check now

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String sSignupResponse = gson.toJson(signUpResponse);
```

instead of

```
String sSignupResponse = gson.toJson(signUpResponse, SuccessResponse.class);
```

Comment: Hey @Bhupat Bheda,you  can Check my answer above

Answer (score 0):

200 (OK), 201(Created - when you insert something in server database) and 204(No content - server has processed your request and it don't return nothing instead) are corect. Check [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for all response codes in `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Thanks !!can you tel me the reason,why i am  not able to show the data ,I want to show something to the user,which was resides in the 202 response

Comment: Please post your JSON response

Comment: {"mesage":"hello you are already registered.","code":"some thing already exists"}

Comment: And `SuccessResponse` class, please.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood how `SerializedName` is used. With this annotation you match the key of json object that need to be serialized/deserialized. All your objects have the same key, `key`. In this response you have only 2 string objects, `message` and `code`. You need to map your class to those 2 objects.

Comment: Your `SuccessResponse ` does not match the response. Also using Gson, you could make retrofit to return your needed object like `Call<SuccesResponse> call =...`. You don't need to convert them mannualy.

Comment: more detail will help me a lot.What should i write in SuccessResponse class, which is nothing but the response which comes in the form of JOSN right ?that's what i have written !!

Comment: Look into documentation: http://square.github.io/retrofit/. And you can't display nothing because your fields from Success class are null.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `REST` `response` code [HERE](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

If `response` `code` is match with format `2xx`, that means success.
So, in you case you should check `response.isSuccessful()` to check if the `response` is `success` or not instead of check `response` code by manual

Comment: So finally you want me to check response.isSuccessful instead of responsecode==200 and 201 like.right ?Can you tell me why i  am not getting response in JSON format !!

Comment: Yes, u r right, You should check response.isSuccessful instead of responsecode==200 and 201.
The main reason why you not getting json format in response is belong to server side. Normally when your request is create/delete something, server just returns only result code (or something not like json format)/

Comment: I want to show something to the user,which was resides in the 202 response

Comment: in your case I suggest you should base on response code to display correct message for users. Example (201 --> Created Success, 202 --> Request Accepted). Take a look at response code table to get more details

Comment: It's Okay .can't you help me how to display the data which resides under 202 response like i did in 200 response!! Thanks

Comment: when i use that ,what i got is Expected receiver of type com.xxxx.models.SuccessResponse, but got retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall

Comment: in case response code is 201 or 202 that means server does not return any message so you must define your own message to display for users

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer,Just do like this .You know upfront the 202 Response.So make a POJO class Response202.Now let SuccessResponse Class inherit the properties of Response Class.You are done now

```
SuccessResponse response202 = response.body();
                        Gson gson202 = new Gson();
                        String json202Str = gson202.toJson(response202, SuccessResponse.class);
```