# Retrofit successfully return data over wifi but fails over Mobile Data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to get some data from a web service. 
The retrofit is giving successful response over Wifi but whenever i use the mobile data the retrofit is giving failure response.

Api Class

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.jivansath.com/api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

RestApis Interface Class

```
public interface RestApis {


@GET("User/LoadAlert")
Call<AlertsPOJO> getAlert();

}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RestApis apiService =
            Api.getClient().create(RestApis.class);

    Call<AlertsPOJO> call = apiService.getAlert();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AlertsPOJO>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AlertsPOJO>call, Response<AlertsPOJO> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                AlertsPOJO.Response response1 = response.body().getResponse();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success " + response1.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error " + response.errorBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AlertsPOJO>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

}
```

AlertPOJO Class

```
public class AlertsPOJO {

@SerializedName("successcode")
@Expose
private Integer successcode;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Response response;

public Integer getSuccesscode() {
    return successcode;
}

public void setSuccesscode(Integer successcode) {
    this.successcode = successcode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
}
```

Response

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private Integer type;
@SerializedName("videourl")
@Expose
private String videourl;
@SerializedName("ImageURL")
@Expose
private String imageURL;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("isactive")
@Expose
private Boolean isactive;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Integer type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getVideourl() {
    return videourl;
}

public void setVideourl(String videourl) {
    this.videourl = videourl;
}

public String getImageURL() {
    return imageURL;
}

public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Boolean getIsactive() {
    return isactive;
}

public void setIsactive(Boolean isactive) {
    this.isactive = isactive;
}

}}
```

Can anyone guide me why the api successfully works over wifi and fails over mobile data.

Comment: post your both logs

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers D/Error Message :: Unable to resolve host "www.jivansath.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: I believe this is the issue with the mobile data, not with Retrofit

Comment: check this line is in your manifest:- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @SejpalPavan permission is already there

Comment: set timeout in retrofit builder if connection was not proper api calling will stop

Comment: Gson gson=new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

Comment: @SejpalPavan same error

Comment: try to check apn protocol in your sim card access point and chang it to ipv4 and then check

Comment: i dont think so this can be a good practice.

Comment: @Wasif which device you are using? currently which OS running on the device?

Comment: i am using Samsung s8 with android 9.1

Comment: @Wasif Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739479/2941375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add network config file to res folder

[image: network-file-in-res folder]

**network-security-config:**

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">your domain here</domain>
</domain-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config></network-security-config>
```

and add a line in manifest file application tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have the INTERNET permission.
Add this to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) client with your retrofit code. Follow below step.

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

Then Call this code In retrofit where you build your URL.

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Add the connection timeout to max. This may be an issue with low connectivity on mobile phone.

Comment: No progress. I am using 4g but still the same error of Unable to resolve host "www.jivansath.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: @Wasif Are they ASP.NET Webservice

Comment: Yes they are ASP.NET Services

Comment: @Wasif Try to run on POSTMAN first and then share here here

Comment: {"successcode":202,"message":"","response":{"id":1,"type":5,"videourl":"Uploads/Videos/apps/add1.mp4","ImageURL":"","Description":"Hy News alert","isactive":true}}

Comment: Then it based on Web Service Issue says HTTP  202 Accepted. The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation.

Comment: So what can be solution to this problem?

Comment: It should be HTTP 200 OK for parsing.

Comment: @Wasif ask developer to change webservice and test it on POSTMAN for 200 OK HTTP response

Comment: @Wasif Parse it then.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a HTTP 202 vs 200 issue on server side processing, try to apply this:
[another answer on a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43729977/9240709)